# Why can't class variables be used in __init__ keyword arg?

Tags: python, class, variables, keyword-argument

I can't find any documentation on when exactly a class can reference itself. In the following it will fail. This is because the class has been created but not initialized until after `__init__`'s first line, correct?

```
class A(object):
    class_var = 'Hi'
    def __init__(self, var=A.class_var):
        self.var = var
```

So in the use case where I want to do that is this the best solution:

```
class A(object):
    class_var = 'Hi'
    def __init__(self, var=None)
        if var is None:
            var = A.class_var
        self.var = var
```

Any help or documentation appreciated!

Comment: you forgot to add in the __init__(self)   just saying :)

Comment: @FelixFeliciant I'm sick, but didn't realize I was that tired. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python scripts are interpreted as you go. So when the interpreter enters `__init__()` the class variable `A` isn't defined yet (you are inside it), same with `self` (that is a different parameter and only available in function body).

However anything in that class is interpreted top to bottom, so `class_var` is defined so you can simply use that one.

```
class A(object):
    class_var = 'Hi'
    def __init__(self, var=class_var):
        self.var = var
```

but I am not super certain that this will be stable across different interpreters...

Comment: Note: If, for some reason, you wanted different defaults in subclasses (without the subclass needing to redefine `__init__`), you'd need to use the lazy initialization approach (`def __init__(self, var=None):`, `if var is None: var = self.class_var`). Default parameters are bound at definition time, not at run time, so binding the default to `class_var` directly will mean `class B(A): class_var = 'Bye'` would still have a default `var` of `'Hi'` unless you overwrote `__init__` to replace it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd recommend lazy initialization too. More reliable and more readable code.